# Copy constructor for a pointer data linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Can you help me to write a copy constructor for this List, note that the Data is stored indirectly.

```
     class List {
         private:
         struct Node {
            Data *data;
            Node *next;
         };
         Node *head;
    };
```

You can assume you have a copy constructor of Data class.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd rather assume you put more effort into this than asking someone else to do it for you. I'm probably wrong, but I'd still like to. There are *thousands* of examples of copy-ctors, many of which will probably help you. What have you learned from them, and what did you try so far ?

Comment: It depends on how you want to manage the memory those pointers. Will you copy those items themselves by making new allocations? If you want to share those allocated objects between copied lists, will you use a smart pointer type e.g. `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Your class definition needs to add the function signature:

```
List(const List& list);
```

The parameter is the list you are copying from.

You also need to implement this function.

```
  List::List(const List& list)
  {
    //Iterate through the list parameter's nodes, and recreate the list
    //exactly as it is in the list you passed in.
  }
```

Note that you probably ***don't*** want to do this:

```
  List::List(const List& list)
  {
    head = list.head;
  }
```

because instead of being a copy of the list, it's actually a second reference to the *same* list.

You can call this function like this:

```
List thisIsAPremadeList;
List copyOfList(thisIsAPremadeList);
```

And now copyOfList contains a deep copy of everything that thisIsAPremadeList has.