# Copy constructor for List class without using any methods in implementation

Tags: c++, constructor

I was working for writing a copy constructor for List class with requirement as not to use any other methods in implementation.

The class fragment is as follows :

```
class List {
     private:
     struct Node {
            NodeData *data;
            Node *next;
           };
           Node *head;
 };
```

**The requirement is to write copy constructor for this class and do not use any other methods in implementation except that we may use copy constructor for NodeData class**

I have written the copy constructor as follows:

```
list::list(const list &t){
  Node* q;
  q=new Node;
  while (p!=NULL){
    q->x= p->x;}
}
```

This is not working, please help in how to write the copy constructor as required.

Comment: Well, at least it's a step in the right direction; [better than before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523112/copy-constructor-for-a-pointer-data-linked-list). If your *exact* requirements are to write a copy-ctor, you've done it (right or wrong). If it doesn't function as you expect (which it seems it doesn't, from your comment "This is not working"), then you know more than you're telling here; namely *how* you expect it to work, and how that differs from what it is actually doing per the code you wrote.

Comment: Why do you never use your parameter `const list &t` + consider making deep copies of data  instead of shallow copies. This should not even compile since `struct Node` does not have a field `x`.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly I'm wondering if some random code was typed to "fulfil the requirement" of showing "what you've tried".

Comment: @CraigYoung Yes I am pretty sure he did not try to compile. But more importantly without a specific error message or line or result, we'll be better off talking about cats :)!

Comment: @user4581301 but this exercise will teach 1) why you shouldn't reinvent the wheel  2) how the wheel works.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly Well.... many problems are solvable with specific message or line numbers. But in this case OP wanted someone to do his work for him. And his code is so incoherent (as you say: "probably did not even try to compile") that to answer the question would be to do OP's work for him.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the commentors that this is a moronic exercise, actually its interesting to try and do this. The following should give you an idea on what to try: http://ideone.com/DdC7bN

```
class List {
private:
    struct Node {
        int data; // simplification
        Node *next;

        Node(int d) {
            data = d;
            next = NULL;
        }
    };

protected:
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

  public:  
    List(int d) : head(new Node(d)), tail(head) {}

    void append(int d) {
        Node* n = new Node(d);
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
    }

    List(const List& rhs) {
        if (head) delete head;

        head=new Node(rhs.head->data);

        Node* lhsCurrent = head;
        Node* rhsCurrent = rhs.head->next;
        do {
            lhsCurrent->next = new Node(rhsCurrent->data);  

            rhsCurrent = rhsCurrent->next;
            lhsCurrent = lhsCurrent->next;                  
        } while (rhsCurrent!=NULL);

        tail = lhsCurrent;
    }
 }; 

int main() {
    List first(5);
    first.append(6);

    List second(first);
    return 0;
}
```